# pinax ImportError cannot import name UserOpenidAssociation

Tags: python, django, pinax

I have these errors:

`ImportError at` / `cannot import name UserOpenidAssociation`.

I could not make any sense out of the traceback:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.1.1
Python Version: 2.6.1
Installed Applications:
['inventory.inlanddbase']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django_openid.consumer.SessionConsumer',
 'account.middleware.LocaleMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.doc.XViewMiddleware',
 'pagination.middleware.PaginationMiddleware',
 'pinax.middleware.security.HideSensistiveFieldsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  83.                     request.path_info)
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  216.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in _get_url_patterns
  245.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in _get_urlconf_module
  240.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "C:\inlanddoors\Scripts\inventory\urls.py" in <module>
  9. from account.openid_consumer import PinaxConsumer
File "C:\inlanddoors\Lib\site-packages\pinax\apps\account\openid_consumer.py" in <module>
  15. from account.views import login as account_login
File "C:\inlanddoors\Lib\site-packages\pinax\apps\account\views.py" in <module>
  22.     from django_openid.models import UserOpenidAssociation

Exception Type: ImportError at /
Exception Value: cannot import name UserOpenidAssociation
```

What am I  doing wrong???

Comment: Most likely you don't have django_openid installed or it's not on your python path. Go to the python shell and try `django_openid.models import UserOpenidAssociation`.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo pip install django_openid`

Comment: > sudo pip install django_openid
        Downloading/unpacking django-openid
        Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement    django-openid
No distributions at all found for django-openid